# Watson Conversation API when to use which package?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

The https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk has been around for a while.  I just noticed https://www.npmjs.com/package/conversation-extension-framework

Any hints on when to use one over the other, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the authors of the [`watson-developer-cloud`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud) npm package.

The `watson-developer-cloud` npm package provides access to all the Watson services, not only Conversation. You could combine conversation with Speech to Text and Text to Speech using the same library. It also provides access to all the features the API has, you can create intents, entities, workspaces, etc.

After looking at `conversation-extension-framework` I found that it has some good features like associating API calls with context variables.

Finally, there are other packages besides the two mentioned in your question.
For example, if you are using botkit, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/botkit-middleware-watson to connect it to Conversation.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated